# How do I find the shortest way through a list of connected waypoints?

Tags: c#, path-finding

```
public class Waypoint
{
    System.Drawing.Point _loc = new System.Drawing.Point();
    public System.Drawing.Point Location { get { return _loc; } }

    List<Waypoint> _connections = new List<Waypoint>();
    public List<Waypoint> Connections { get { return _connections; } }

    public Waypoint() { }

    public Waypoint(int x, int y) { _loc = new System.Drawing.Point(x, y); }
}
```

... is my class of Waypoints.
I need to find the shortest way from `Waypoint A` to `Waypoint B`.
The waypoints are inter-connected. (example: `X.Connections` contains `Y` so `Y.Connections` contains `X`)
When I designed the system, I have had in mind a way to find them... But it doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want is the [A*](http://www-cs-students.stanford.edu/%7Eamitp/gameprog.html) algorithm.

A* is an extension of the [Dijkstra's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm) but uses a heuristic to estimate the distance left to the final destination (like [breadth-first-search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search) does). It is the best of both worlds. :)

The Amit's pages are great to learn the whole algorithm but for a smoother introduction check out [this link](https://web.archive.org/web/20171022224528/http://www.policyalmanac.org:80/games/aStarTutorial.htm). It took me a while to understand how A* works but the time spent learning it was really worth it in my opinion.

Comment: Yes... But anything in C# that I don't really have to understand?

Comment: If you want my opinion, it's better to understand A* than simply copying code and it will also help you in the long run, but do as you wish. :)

Answer (score 2):

You're describing the [Shortest path problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shortest-path).
Wikipedia has a list of algorithms.

Comment: Yes... But anything in C# that I don't really have to understand?

Comment: I don't want to make it my code... Plus I can understand someone else's code.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this most simply by performing a [breadth first search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search) from the initial point until the waypoint is reached.

Comment: This seems to me like the sanest way. I will try to translate the pseudocode.